# python Kafka manage consumer/producer process management library

Tags: python, process, apache-kafka

What is a good python library to manage Kafka consumer and producer processes? There could be between 20-50 processes.

Is it better to put these in separate scripts and use something like cron or build them as 1 application with a process management library? Celery or redis or something..

Thanks